# Configuring flume to read logs from different directories

Tags: hadoop, file-transfer, flume

Different applications are writing their logs to different directory structure. I want to read those logs and put it in sink(can be hadoop or physical file).
How does flume supports multiple sources for single agent? is it possible to have multiple sources for a single agent ? 
Can anyone guide me in this?

Thanks and regards
Chhaya

Answer (score 0):

Configure your flume agent with multiple sources - one for each log file. They should probably be spooling file source type. Note that when the source gets the file it needs to not change - you need to configure the source to be sure of this..

Those sources can then go to a single channel which can have a single sink.

Comment: thanks for your reply..i will give it a try..and i need multiple sink